# Lenovo G580 Wireless/bluetooth function key problem

Tags: wireless, 13.04, bluetooth, lenovo

I'm using Lenovo G580. when I turn WiFi/Bluetooth on with <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, it's actually not turning on. To turn it on, I need to restart. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I have the same computer and I **cannot** reproduce this. If I hit Fn+F5 it turns it off, when I hit it again it turns it on again. Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the software switch back on by executing the following command in a terminal:

`rfkill unblock all`